# Bracket Checker Using Stack and Queue in C#

Tags: c#, validation

I am having an issue solving  Bracket Checker .
i cant seem to solve the problem if user input this sequence of bracket then my program must print its not a right sequence

Input:

## ({}[)

Output:

## Not a Right Sequence

My code is below

```
        Stack s = new Stack();

        Queue q = new Queue();

        bool isok = true;

        string FinalData = "0";            

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Brackets");

        string data = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data.Substring(i, 1) == "{"
             || data.Substring(i, 1) == "["
             || data.Substring(i, 1) == "("
                )
            {
                s.Push(data.Substring(i, 1));
            }
            else
            {
                q.Enqueue(data.Substring(i, 1));
            }
        }
        while (s.Count > 0 && q.Count > 0)
        {
            FinalData = (String)s.Pop();
            string value = (String)q.Dequeue();
            if (FinalData == value)
            {
                isok = false;
                break;
            }                 
        }

        if (isok)
            Console.WriteLine(data + " is a Right Sequence.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(data + " is Not a Right Sequence.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: If you explain what "bracket checker" is _supposed_ to do, perhaps we can begin to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Oded: Bracket checker is that checks the brackets are in the right Sequence means (scanner for missing and mismatched brackets) if some brackets are missing or mismatched its gives the error to the user. For Example This is a correct Sequence of Brackets ([]{}),({}),({}),{()}

Comment: I think, you better use characters instead of substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean isCorrect;

public boolean checkBraces(String braces)
{
    Stack<Character>stack = new Stack<Character>();
    int openBCount = 0;
    int closeBCount = 0;                                                                

    for(int c = 0; c<=braces.length()-1; c++)
    {
        //check for open braces push to stack

        if(braces.charAt(c)=='{' || braces.charAt(c)=='[' ||braces.charAt(c)=='(')
        {


            stack.push(braces.charAt(c));
            openBCount++;

        }                                                                       ////check for close braces. pop the open braces
                                                                                 //compare it to the closed braces using the the 
                                                                                 //method ValidatePerBraces                                                                      
                                                                                 //therefor checking for CORRECTNEES of how the braces                                                                       //are closed
        else if(braces.charAt(c)=='}' || braces.charAt(c)==']' || braces.charAt(c)==')')
        {

            closeBCount++;
            if(!ValidatePerBraces(stack.pop(), braces.charAt(c))) 
            {
                isCorrect = false; //return false in case where they dont match
                return isCorrect;
            }

        }
                                //for braces to be complete, open and close braces
                                //should be even, if they are not even then it is 
                                //for sure wrong at least for the specification.
        if(c>=braces.length()-1)
        {

            if(openBCount != closeBCount)
            {
                isCorrect = false; 
                return isCorrect;
            }
        }

    }


    isCorrect = true; // true if they all match

    return isCorrect;
}

// returns true if validated
public boolean ValidatePerBraces(char a, char b)
{

    return a == '(' && b== ')' || a == '[' &&  b == ']' || a == '{' && b== '}' ;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'l give you a few hints and the basic idea:

- you don't need the Queue, just a `Stack<char>`.
- read the input, for each char:

  - if the char is an open brace, push it
  - if the char is a close brace, pop the stack and compare.
  - discard other chars

Comment: i have an assignment regarding using stack and queue i have to solve this problem by using both of them .

Comment: @Prozek, you can solve that by calling a Stack a LIFO queue. Look it up.

Comment: i have solved this problem by stack also now i am solving this problem by both stack an queue

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CheckBraces(string data)
{
    Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
    foreach(char c in data){
        switch(c){
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{':
                stack.Push(c);
                break;
            case ')':
            case ']':
            case '}':
                if(!CheckMatch(stack.Pop(),c)){
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
   }
   return true;
}

private bool CheckMatch(char a, char b){
   return a=='(' && b==')' || 
          a=='[' && b==']' ||
          a=='{' && b=='}';
}
```

Comment: This is what I described half an hour ago. You are lacking a Queue too.

Comment: And what about: `bool CheckMatch(char a, char b) { return a==b; }`

Answer (score 0):

Thannks Guys I have Solved The Problem Using stack And Queue Both AT the Same time. Here's the code

```
        Stack s = new Stack();

        Queue q = new Queue();

        bool isRight = true;

        char OpeningBracket = ' ';

        char closingBracket = ' ';

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Brackets");
        string data = Console.ReadLine();
        char[] character = data.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < character.Length; i++)
        {
            if (character[i] == '(' || character[i] == '{' ||
                character[i] == '[')
            {
                s.Push(character[i]);
            }
            else
                q.Enqueue(character[i]);
        }

        if (s.Count == 0 || q.Count == 0)            
            isRight = false;

        while (s.Count > 0 && q.Count > 0)
        {
            OpeningBracket = (char)s.Pop();
            closingBracket = (char)q.Dequeue();
            if ((OpeningBracket == '(' && closingBracket != ')')
           ||   (OpeningBracket == '[' && closingBracket != ']')
           ||   (OpeningBracket == '{' && closingBracket != '}')
                )
            {
                isRight = false;
            }

        }

        if (isRight)
            Console.WriteLine(data + " is a Right Sequence.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(data + " is Not Right Sequence.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: And did you notice how illogical this is?

Comment: @Henk : What Do you MEAN by How ILLogical is this ??

Comment: Using a Queue and a Stack for exactly the same task (and doing that task twice).

Comment: @Henk your Right!bUT i was expermenting on this problem so thats why i used queue and stack :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static bool IsCorrectBracketSeq(string sequence)
    {

        var stack = new Stack<char>();
        foreach (var sign in sequence)
        {
            if(sign == '(' || sign == '[' || sign == '{')
                stack.Push(sign);
            else if (sign == ')' || sign == ']' || sign == '}')
            {
                if (!stack.Any())
                    return false;
                
                var topSing = stack.Pop();
                var str = $"{topSing}{sign}";
                if (str != "[]" && str != "{}" && str != "()")
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return stack.Count == 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static bool IsBracesValidator(string input)
{
    bool IsValidBraces = true;

    char[] chrArray = input.ToCharArray();

    List<Char> foundOpenParanthesis = new List<char>();
    List<Char> foundClosedParanthesis = new List<char>();

    char[] chrOpenParanthesis = { '{', '[', '(', '<' };
    char[] chrClosedParanthesis = { '}', ']', ')', '>' };
    for (int i = 0; i <= chrArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (chrOpenParanthesis.Contains(chrArray[i]))
        {
            foundOpenParanthesis.Add(chrArray[i]);
        }

        if (chrClosedParanthesis.Contains(chrArray[i]))
        {
            foundClosedParanthesis.Add(chrArray[i]);
        }
    }

    if (foundOpenParanthesis.Count == foundClosedParanthesis.Count)
    {
        for(int i=0;i< foundOpenParanthesis.Count;i++)
        {
            char chr = foundOpenParanthesis[i];
            switch (chr)
            {
                case '[': chr = ']'; break;
                case '<': chr = '>'; break;
                case '(': chr = ')'; break;
                case '{': chr = '}'; break;
            }

            if (!chr.Equals(foundClosedParanthesis[foundClosedParanthesis.Count - i-1]))
            {
                IsValidBraces = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        IsValidBraces = false;
    }

    return IsValidBraces;
}
```